# Counter for parallel processes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallel-processing

I have this code that uses the parallel gem to split work among different processes.

```
Parallel.map(list, :in_processes=>4) do |item|
    if item.name == "A"
        puts "A"
    else
        puts "B"
    end
end
```

What would be the best way to have a counter shared between the processes in order to get the exact number of times I got A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receive the Parallel's returned value (array of returned values from each iteration), and use Array#count method.

```
list = ["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"]
result = Parallel.map(list, :in_processes=>4) do |item|
  if item == "A"
    puts "Got A"
    return "A"
  else
    puts "Got B"
    return "B"
  end
end

result # Array of "A" and "B" like ["A","B","A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"]
# Now, you can do whatever you want with the result array.
count_a = result.count("A") # 5
count_b = result.count("B") # 5
```

(Ruby doesn't need explicit return keyword, but I put it to avoid any misunderstandings.)